# Discord.py on member update does not work

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was developing a bot on discord, and I want to log when user roles changes. I tried the code below and that was just starting.

```py
TOKEN = ""

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message)

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print(before)
    print(after)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

When I type message to a channel, It prints the message to python console, However, when I add role to myself in the same guild, It does not print anything.

**Note: I enabled `presence intent` and `server member intent` in discord developer portal**

Comment: presence, members intents should be enabled in discord developer portal, and also through the code.

Comment: What is before, what is after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intents should be enabled both on the portal and the code itself.

Here is how you do it in the code.

```py
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

And according to the [docs of on_memebr_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update)

`This requires Intents.members to be enabled.`

That is why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should activate that from your code like:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
client= discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

[reference for more information](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)